# How to save a filename in a variable in Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm new to Nifi and I'm trying to get a file name and save this filename in a variable to be used later on in the process.

Basically I have a file(data_yyyyMMdd.tar.gz) which contains 2 .txt files(1.txt and 2.txt), and before to unpack this file, I want to save it's name to a variable and then, use this variable to add content to the unpacked files.

content of the files(originally) :
1.txt
id|name
1|apple
2|orange

content of the files after be updated with the filename
id|name|filename
1|apple|data_yyyyMMdd.tar.gz
2|orange|data_yyyyMMdd.tar.gz

I managed to unpack to file successfully, but, I'm not being able to save the .tar.gz filename in a variable and add it's value to the content of each file.

Could you guys help me?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what processor you used to get the tar.gz file, you likely already have a FlowFile attribute called `filename` set to the name of the tar.gz file. After unpacking you may find that the filename attribute is overwritten (not sure though), so before unpacking, copy the filename attribute into some other attribute using UpdateAttribute. For example you can add a property in UpdateAttribute named `original.filename` and set its value to `${filename}`.

After unpacking you can use UpdateRecord to add the original filename as a field in each record, I think by setting the Replacement Value Strategy to `Literal Value` and adding a property `/filename` set to `${original.filename}`. I haven't tried this so I don't know if these are exactly the right settings, but the approach should work.

Comment: Hi Matty thanks for your reply, I think you got the idea, now,I will try your suggestion, just one question, once I have created the UpdateAttribute with the with the property original.filename added, should I connect this processor to the Updaterecord processor or I just need to add a property re to the ${original.filename}? Thanks again